# Is there a faster way to perform this MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two collections, Stops and Services for a city bus tracking app.
Here are the schemas:

```
var ServiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, index: true},
    description: String,
    service_type: String,
    routes: {type: Array, "default": []}
});
```

"routes", above, is an array of objects and each object has a field called "stops" which is an array of stop_id, each of which indexes to a Stop document.

```
var StopSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    stop_id: {type: Number, index: true},
    name: String,
    identifier: String,
    locality: String,
    orientation: Number,
    direction: String,
    coordinates : {type: [Number], index: '2d'},
    destinations: { type: Array, "default": []},
    services: {type: Array, "default": []}
});
```

I want to find all Stop documents indexed by the stop_ids within a given service.  I used a for loop.

```
var stops = db.services.findOne().routes[0].stops;
stops.forEach(function(j,k){
    printjson(db.stops.findOne({stop_id: j}));
});
```

Does this seem correct, or is there a more sophisticated (faster)
way I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the stops in a route in one `find` query by using [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in).

In the shell:

```js
var route_stop_ids = db.services.findOne().routes[0].stops;
var stops = db.stops.find({stop_id: {$in: route_stop_ids}})
```

Comment: Does that execute faster as well?

Comment: @michaelAdam Yes, it's just one query instead of one per stop.

Comment: But doesn't that query have to involve a loop inside?

Comment: @michaelAdam No, think of it as MongoDB only needing to perform a single set intersection between `route_stop_ids` and the index on `stop_id`.